# How to redirect two domains in ssl?

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have the domain englishname.ca than I want to redirect to englishname.com. I did some configuration and it works with HTTP but not with https. But I go to http://englishname.ca, I'm redirected to http://englishname.com but when I go to https://englishname.ca, I'm not redirected.

This is my conf :

```
server {                                                                                                               
        server_name 162.243.216.109 staging.frenchname.com staging.englishname.ca staging.singularenglishname.com;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  $scheme://staging.englishname.com/$1 permanent;                                  
} 

server {
        listen 80 default deferred;
        server_name www.englishname.com staging.englishname.com;                               
        root /home/deployer/apps/site/current/public;   

        location ^~ /assets/ {                                                                                         
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
        location @unicorn {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://unicorn;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
        listen 443 default ssl;
        server_name www.englishname.com staging.englishname.com;
        root /home/deployer/apps/site/current/public;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www.englishname.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www.englishname.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols sslv3 tlsv1 tlsv1.1 tlsv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
        location @unicorn {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://unicorn;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: I don't see any redirection above.

Comment: The 6 first lines are my redirection.

Comment: I think I had better leave this to someone who understands nginx better than I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I simply added those lines :

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name 162.243.216.109 staging.lescollectionneursassocies.com staging.associatedartcollectors.ca staging.associatedartcollector.com;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  $scheme://staging.associatedartcollectors.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

It's the same lines than the beggin but with `listen 443`.